# Generic manipulation of abstract data type objects

Tags: c++, algorithm

> The data structures that we use in applications often contain a great
>   deal of information of various types, and certian pieces of
>   information may be belong to multiple independent data structures. For
>   example, a file of personnel data may contain records with names,
>   addresses, and various other pieces of information about employees;
>   and each record may need to belong to one data structure for searching
>   for particular employees, to another data structure for answering
>   statistical queries, and so forth.
>
> Despite this diverstiy and complexity, a large class of computing
>   applications involve generic manipulation of data objects, and need
>   access to the information associated with them for a limited number of
>   specific reasons. Many of the manipulations that are required are a
>   natural outgrowth of basic computational procedures, so they are
>   needed in broad variety of applications. Many of the fundamental
>   algorithms can be applied effectively to the task of building a layer
>   of abstraction that can provide client programs with the ability to
>   perform such amanipulations efficiently. Thus we shall consider in
>   detail numerous ADT's that are associated with such maniupulations.
>   They define various operations on collections of abstract objects,
>   independent of the type of the object.

Above text is described in context of abstract data types by Robert Sedwick in Algorithms in C++.

My questions are

What does author mean by "a large class of computing applications involve generic manipulation of data objects and need access to the information associated with them for a limited number of specific reasons." ? Here what does author mean by generic manipulation and limited number of specific reasons?

What does author mean by "building a layer of abstraction " so that client programs can perform such manipuations effieciently" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generic manipulation is when you write code that can process some data without explicitly knowing what type of data it is, just how you can manipulate it.

Consider std::find from the C++ library:

```
template<class InputIterator, class T>
InputIterator find(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& value)
{
    for ( ; first != last; ++first) 
        if (*first == value)
            return first;

    return last;
}
```

This code works for any sequence that can provide an iterator (not just containers), and *any* type `T` that can be passed by reference and compared using `==`.

You don't have to know anything else about `T`.

Answer (score 0):

I think abstract interfaces are meant, their proper implemintation allow client not to sank in details of realization and therefore perform actions efficiently and actions on different types of generic objects what were derived from abstract class. Also I think templates are covered here that are core of generic programming

Answer (score 0):

By creating the objects your programs (algorightms) work on, you translate the actual problem into something that computer can understand. There's usually more than way to do the job; what's important to pick the model that's not only efficient in terms of computing, but also allows the code to be readable and easy maintainable.

As the generic algorithms can run only on generic data, abstract layer of access to your code means you can efficiently change the algorithms, without much ado concerned with the data interface.

As long as the interface remains the same, the implementation can be changed. It means the code (or desing) is complete and focused on one task. Avoiding complicated links between various program parts leads to solutions that are much easier to test, debug and extend.

Answer (score 0):

He's basically describing what the STL does. I'm not hating on Sedgewick, it's a classic and I bought my copy in 1986 but he's writing for a very unsophisticated world. Use the algorithms by all means but I'd tune out anything to do with general software engineering and read something more recent.

Comment: Oh just seen you have Algorithms in C++ (1992) rather than the original Algorithms. This bizarrely has a publication date of 1988 although I thought I had it in 1986 ... 1987 at the latest. Anyway my point remains the same.